# Is there anyway to tell if an openCV cap.read() call will fail before it begins to parse a video?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, h.264

Problem: I am per frame parsing very long videos with a complex algorithm for AI applications in python. This is a slow and long process even using multiprocessing and threading tricks. Therefore it is very annoying when it dies half way through its process due to an open CV issue with the video.

Request: Does anyone know a good way in python for open cv to raise an error before it begins to parse a video if the video would later throw a fatal error or None from cap.read()? An added bonus would for the solution to at least give me a frame number and a reason so that I may edit or reconvert the video to fix this.

Latest Issue:

```
[h264 @ 0x41cad80] Invalid NAL unit size (-66445153 > 10189).
[h264 @ 0x41cad80] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `VideoCapture` bit of OpenCV is just a convenience thing for prototyping. If you want anything more that bare-bones, lowest common denominator utility that reads a bunch of frames from some camera, use a library designed for that... probably ffmpeg, since that's one of the backends OpenCV uses. | I haven't heard of `read()` throwing exception much, generally if something fails, it returns False as the first part of the result tuple and an empty frame. Both cases are trivial to handle.

Comment: Any good documentation / suggestions of direct interfacing the video libraries? I have some experience connecting to g streamer and that was not fun.

Comment: Not really. Are those videos stored locally (i.e. this is not streaming, right?). Are those failures reproducible (as in, is it a problem with the data, like corrupted file?). Presumably just decoding that file without doing any processing on it is orders of magnitude faster than when you have the AI in there?

Comment: related (same question?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74483528/series-what-causes-python-opencv-to-give-this-error-invalid-nal-unit-size

Comment: @aris-t If still not solved... **(1)** For _"...To raise an error before it begins"_ if you want to preview or test some code result then you can try using the `Try.. Catch` options. Search `Python try catch` for tutorials (or just [read this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)). The **exception** part is where you can run some other function to handle the failing (eg: maybe start a **timer** to wait 2 seconds and then re-try doing the same function/code again?). **(2)** Is there really only 2 lines in the **full error message**???

Comment: @VC.One | Thanks for the suggestion. The timer and try except approaches are not the best in this context as I process the video using multiprocessing in chunks. Even in single threaded processing the try except would fail gracefully but only once time has been invested. I wish to fail within the first couple frames to avoid investing more.

Comment: @Dan Mašek | Yes the videos are stored locally. I am looking for a general solution that would abort video processing if the file was corrupted, bad formatting, bad block etc. Your recommendation on doing an an initial fast decoding is interesting. Would you have any recommendation on how to do this with open CV?

Comment: @aris-t **(1)** OK I thought you wanted to test the function itself. If you're worried about the input file giving errors then yes do as @ DanMasek said (_eg:_ a test decoding). You can test by simply reading the frames (no extra processing). **(2)** Are you decoding an **H.264** file or an **MP4** file (containing H.264 video data)? I wonder why _"Invalid NAL unit size"_ if using raw H264 (because that format never uses sizes, only start codes for each NAL units)...

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a shot when I get back to this problem again. the file is a .mp4 with I believe h.264 encoding but honestly the solution can't make that assumption. The tool is more general purpose video processing.

Comment: wrong library. use ffmpeg directly, or via PyAV. OpenCV's purpose is computer vision, not seeking in video files.